# How to add page header with a black horizontal line in Office Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-word-2013

I simply need header like this:

[image]

but with a black horizontal line instead of a blue one. How to do this in Word 2013?

Comment: Select the header contents. Then right-click the selection and go to Page Limits (or something in the likes). From there you can alter the border settings.

Answer (score 19):

On the `Home tab` under `Paragraph` click the `Borders` icon (the same one used to change the borders of tables) and from there select `Horizontal line` which inserts a line with black color by default.

To insert the title control go to the `Insert tab` and click `Quick Parts`, `Document Property` and then choose `Title`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to insert the lines.

Detailed steps are given in the link below.

http://www.guidingtech.com/12848/insert-horizontal-lines-ms-word-office/

I normally use ___ and hit Enter. It gives a solid black line and takes care of the spacing and placing.